# element web-app must be declared

Tags: jakarta-ee, web.xml

I checked out this project from svn repository into IDEA and the web.xml xsd looks like this:

```
<web-app id="data-fabric-web-tool" version="2.5"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

The very first error I see is "Element web-app" must be declared.
Also I am getting "cannot resolve symbol" error for every tag in the file.

Answer (score 8):

According to:

- [Java EE: XML Schemas for Java EE Deployment Descriptors](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/index.html)
- [Java EE 7 Deployment Descriptors](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2013/06/04/java-ee-7-deployment-descriptors/)
- [Java EE 7 Schema Namespace Moving to jcp.org](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/java_ee_schema_namespace_moved)

> All Java EE 7 and newer Deployment Descriptor Schemas share the
>   namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee

Try this descriptor namespace definition:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1" id="data-fabric-web-tool">
</web-app>
```

Comment: typo in end tag: webapp -> web-app

Comment: Did the order of the elements in the tag matter? I was getting an error and a warning about the URL http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd not being able to be loaded in Eclipse 2020-12 for the web.xml but replacing what you had above seemed to get rid of those errors. The difference was I'd had the id then the version and then all the xmlns stuff whereas above you'd had them ahead of the version and id.